# Disable google search input focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop chrome extension to save users favourite urls, so user will click in a button and a popup will appear infront of the website he is visiting allowing him to save his url.
The point is when this popup is been shown while user vistiing google.com, user can't write anything in the popup because google's input is automatically in focus so what should I do to disable this behavior?
[image]

**Note:** This is only happening with google.com

Here is example of my code which is inserted in a shadow dom in any page:

```
<div id="popup">
    <label for="add">Add custom bookmark</label>
    <input type="text" name="add" value="" id="add" autofocus="" placeholder="Please enter an URL...(www.example.com)">
    <a href="#" id="add-bookmark">Submit</a>
    <a href="#" id="close-popup">Close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code of your extension? Or a crx file?

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin Done

Comment: Perhaps Google.com page has a listener on keyDown ? If it has, the listener will be executed before the handlers of your extension, so it will change the focus before the input of text is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the "instant research" feature by clicking on "parameters" onthe bottom of google.com page and then "Research parameter".

Comment: As per the Documentation,
Don't rely on the page having the keyboard focus. The address bar always gets the focus first when the user creates a new tab.
For your reference: (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override)

Comment: And ? He is not using override pages. He was asking to disable the focus changement on the google page, so I have answered.

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin I see your point but how to do programatically, at least disable my code when instant search feature is on!

Comment: Humm it's more dificult. Have you tried to add an event handler on the blur event ? this way you can detect that you have lost the focus and regive it to your input.